How to avoid layout shift while using of :first selector?
I have a table of content, which can be closed and expanded. Closed one has specific height. The expanded one can't have specified height, because different articles have different amount of headings, so the ToC length is different too.
The ToC is inpainted by $('.post-body p:first').before(tocContainer); - and, while testing with Google PageSpeed Test, it causes layout shift, in both of closed and expanded state.
What would be the way to insert ToC on the place I need it without to cause layout shift?

You're adding content to existing content.  By definition, that's going to cause a layout shift.   Whether that's actually a problem is not what the test is telling you.

@fdomn-m I'm aware of this. But I guess I'm not unique with the need to add content to existing one. What is the common way to do so without to cause layout shift?

Do you want your ToC to be visible to the users?  Is it being inserted into existing content?  Regardless of the technical solution, how do you expect to add new content to existing content and have it seen by users without the page being updated?

Existing question that may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143893/avoiding-content-layout-shift-with-inserting-element-after-onload-with-google-ta - tldr either allocate space so there's no shift or load in a way that doesn't shift the content
